# JavaScript recursive replace in Object

Tags: javascript

Folks, I have the following JSON object, in which I would like to recursively find every occurrence of `foo` with `bar`.

Also the `[Object]` can potentially contain `foo` which would also need to be replaced.

```
{ _id: 530797d8952e10129f97fde3,
  Product: 'something',
  Realm: [ 'something', 'something','foo' ],
  Service: 'Node',
  Owners: [ 'foo', 'something' ],
  Project: 'something',
  URLs:
    [ { 'foo': [Object] },
      { 'foo': [Object] },
      { 'foo': [Object] } ] }
```

How would i loop through this?  I've tried with but failed:

```
var cleanObject = {}
for (key in dirtyObject) {
    key = key.replace('foo', 'bar');
    cleanObject[key] = dirtyObject[key];
}
```

Comment: Your title mentions recursion (which seems reasonable) but the code you show doesn't include any. Are you asking how to do recursion? Or is there more code that you haven't shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tip: That's not a "JSON object". There is no such thing as a "JSON object". "JSON" is a string, representing an object. What you have there is an object literal.

However, JSON can help. Consider trying:

```
var cleanObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dirtyObject).replace(/foo/g,'bar'));
```

Comment: That will replace in both keys and values. If I'm reading the question correctly, the OP only wants to replace keys.

Comment: @StephenThomas True. But I'm reading the question as "every occurrence", and the code as a botched attempt to do so that only replaces keys. The question is ambiguous as to that point...

Comment: gotta agree. not sure what the OP really wants here

Comment: Essentially I want EVERY occurrence to be replaced, thanks guys

Comment: And your result worked.  Wish I could award more points to your solution.  This solves a ton of work for me. Thanks

Comment: Of course, this solution only works with alphabetic strings. Don't use it if the search string contains `{}`'s or quotes.

Comment: Maybe not good for all use-cases, but it's a very nice, practical and brutal solution. And it's a one-liner! Nice!